# open 2X separate gedit's in ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, process, gedit

I am wondering if there is a way to force `gedit` (the default text editor in Ubuntu) to open a separate window when opening a second text file, with another already open.

The default behaviour is to use the already open process, and just open a new tab in its window.

Thanks

---

I should add that if I drag the tab for one of the open files out of the window, this opens a separate window. However, I'd like to know if this can be done in a single step.

Answer (score 3):

from `gedit -?`

```
--new-window    Create a new top-level window in an existing instance of gedit
```

So try `gedit --new-window [FILE]`